# Archiving files using Pentaho PDI

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I need to archive the txt file using Pentaho PDI by giving it a dynamic timestamp and append the variable to the output filename. I used get system info which automatically assigns variable as well as value. So my job was Start__ get system info___zip file. In the zip file component, I tried called the variable while giving the output filename along with ${Variable} but the output filename is not coming properly. It should be off filename__timestamp__variable. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you using the Get system info step to get the timestamp as a variable? You don't need to do this, in jobs, the zip file step allows you to add the date to the zip file you create and you can specify the format of that date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split it into two different jobs. First one get system info and second one the file compression. If it does not work, try to pass the variable a as a parameter to the second job.